# using multiple match clauses doesn't return any result in neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am executing the following two queries and i am getting some result.

First query

```
START 
person=node:NODE_TYPE(NODE_TYPE='PERSON') 
MATCH 
(person)-[?:contacts]->(var1)-[?:addresses]->(var2)-[?:details]->(var3)-[?:items]->(var4)-[?:items]->(var5)-[?:value]->(var6) 
WHERE 
var2.`#nodeId` ='at0000' and var3.`#nodeId` ='at0001' and var4.`#nodeId` ='at0002' and var5.`#nodeId` ='at0028' and var6.`value` =~'address.*' 
return distinct person;
```

Second query

```
START 
person=node:NODE_TYPE(NODE_TYPE='PERSON') 
MATCH 
(person)-[?:contacts]->(var1)-[?:addresses]->(var2)-[?:details]->(var3)-[?:items]->(var4)-[?:value]->(var5) 
WHERE 
var2.`#nodeId` ='at0000' and var3.`#nodeId` ='at0001' and var4.`#nodeId` ='at0009' and var5.`value` =~'india.*' 
return distinct person;
```

But when I combine the two queries to a single query to get persons that match both these conditions, it isn't working.

the combined query is

```
START 
person=node:NODE_TYPE(NODE_TYPE='PERSON')  
MATCH 
(person)-[?:contacts]->(var1)-[?:addresses]->(var2)-[?:details]->(var3)-[?:items]->(var4)-[?:items]->(var5)-[?:value]->(var6) , (person)-[?:contacts]->(var7)-[?:addresses]->(var8)-[?:details]->(var9)-[?:items]->(var10)-[?:value]->(var11) 
WHERE 
var2.`#nodeId` ='at0000' and var3.`#nodeId` ='at0001' and var4.`#nodeId` ='at0002' and var5.`#nodeId` ='at0028' and var6.`value` =~'address.*' and 
var8.`#nodeId` ='at0000' and var9.`#nodeId` ='at0001' and var10.`#nodeId` ='at0009' and var11.`value` =~'india.*' 
return distinct person;
```

This query return an empty iterator.

I used 'comma' to combine the MATCH conditions and 'and' to combine the WHERE conditions.
Is there any problem in this?

(I am implementing a query builder to build cypher query. I have to check multiple condition matches. What is the best way to do this?)

```
Neo4j 1.9M04
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. Are you sure that there are any `person`s that meet both of these criteria? That is, are there any `person`s that appear in the result of query 1 and query 2?

Comment: Yes, there are persons that match both the conditions.

Comment: I tried to execute the query without the WHERE clause and i Printed the result including all the 'var's that i use.  
var7,var8,var9,var10,var11 are null for all the results.

var1 and var7 both represent the nodes with relation 'contacts', but var1 has some values and var7 is null.

Comment: That is totally bizarre. I really can't explain that behavior other than guessing that it's a bug (or something else that I'm not seeing). Is it possible for you to set up some example data on console.neo4j.org?

Comment: Is there any way you can recreate this in console.neo4j.org and post the link here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be running into the "identifier uniqueness" condition described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/7ePLU8y93h8) (see first post by Michael Hunger).
If you got a match on the same `(person)` node and have only 1 `:contacts` relation from there, then the identifier `var1` is "using up" the connected node in this match and `var7` can't be assigned to the same node.

In other words, a node found by a match statement can only be used by one identifier within the same `match` statement.

You can try to use a `WITH` clause instead followed by another `MATCH` to work around this issue.

```
START 
person=node:NODE_TYPE(NODE_TYPE='PERSON') 
MATCH 
(person)-[?:contacts]->(var1)-[?:addresses]->(var2)-[?:details]->(var3)-[?:items]->(var4)-[?:items]->(var5)-[?:value]->(var6) 
WHERE 
var2.`#nodeId` ='at0000' and var3.`#nodeId` ='at0001' and var4.`#nodeId` ='at0002' and var5.`#nodeId` ='at0028' and var6.`value` =~'address.*' 
with distinct person
MATCH 
(person)-[?:contacts]->(var1)-[?:addresses]->(var2)-[?:details]->(var3)-[?:items]->(var4)-[?:value]->(var5) 
WHERE 
var2.`#nodeId` ='at0000' and var3.`#nodeId` ='at0001' and var4.`#nodeId` ='at0009' and var5.`value` =~'india.*' 
return distinct person;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i had changed my builder so that identifiers are reused if they occur more than once.