# Order of match-clause affects result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this cypher query...

```
start u = node(251)
match u -[I:PREFERENCE]-> i,
      i <-[Q:CATEGORY|IS_IN*0..]- q <-[C:JOB|LOCATION]- o,
      o -[J:JOB]-> j -[JL:LABEL]-> jl,
      o -[P:LOCATION]-> p -[PL:LABEL]-> pl
where jl.lang = "en"
  and pl.lang = "en"
return distinct o.title, o.description, type(C) as PreferenceType,
      jl.name as Job, pl.name as Location
```

...which isn't quite working yet. The thing is, if I skip the LABEL-relationship, it returns the expected result. However, if I leave it there the result depends on the order of the last two match clauses (`o -[J:JOB]-> j -[JL:LABEL]-> jl` and `o -[P:LOCATION]-> p -[PL:LABEL]-> pl`).

If `LOCATION` is last, I receive only LOCATION-based results and if I put `JOB` on the last position, only JOB-based results.

In the end of course, I want the correct result (including LOCATION- and JOB-based results), but I also wonder why this makes any difference?

I'm using Neo4j `1.9.M03` here

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I'd prefer a version without `WITH`

```
start u = node(251)
match u -[I:PREFERENCE]-> i,
      i <-[Q:CATEGORY|IS_IN*0..]- q <-[C:JOB|LOCATION]- o
 with distinct o, C
match o -[J:JOB]-> j -[JL:LABEL]-> jl,
      o -[P:LOCATION]-> p -[PL:LABEL]-> pl
where jl.lang = "en"
  and pl.lang = "en"
return o.title, o.description, type(C) as PreferenceType,
      jl.name as Job, pl.name as Location
```

Comment: You could try moving the clauses into the where part, since you are trying to filter iirc: WHERE o -[J:JOB]-> j -[JL:LABEL]-> jl AND o-[P:LOCATION]-> p -[PL:LABEL]-> pl

Comment: Just curious, how come it works with the "With" clause. does each o have both the "job" label and the "location" label, or it has only one label which is either "job" or "location"?

Comment: @PhilBa I don't quite understand. I need these clauses to get the multilanguage descriptions (jl.name and pl.name). So moving them to the where part wouldn't work

Comment: @Lisa I don't know, why it works with "with" (yet) ;). I'd like to understand, though. Every "o" has one JOB and one LOCATION relationship to "job" and "location" nodes respectively and these nodes always have LABEL relationships to label-nodes (the where clause ensure that I only get the english label-nodes)

Comment: Sorry, I didnt see that. Meanwhile I found another question which might be relevant to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611723/using-multiple-match-clauses-doesnt-return-any-result-in-neo4j-cypher-query .Basically it boils down to the point that a node/rel which is matched by a MATCH clause, wont be matched again by any other MATCH clause

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It makes sense the "o" must have both job and location labels. it seems to me if you put all of these in the same match, the engine gets confused. for example, the o has two "JOB" relations, one bakcs to the "q", one goes to the "j". I am not sure exactly where it went wrong without seeing an example graph. I don't think you can put the paths in the second match to the "where" clause of the first "match", because you cannot introduce new identifiers in the path in the "where" clause, and then without identifiers like "jl", you cannot get the jl.language.

Comment: @PhilBa To avoid this issue, I used different variable names for every distinct entity. Even for the relationships which I neither need for the WHERE, nor RETURN clause (but only for connecting other nodes). Anyway, if I remove the "JL" and "PL" relationships, it works and those relationships (and their end nodes) are unique in this pattern.

Comment: Then it must have something to do with the fact that the "q" can also be reached from the "o" via a relationsip [:JOB] or [:LOCATION], but the "q" does not have the "JL" or "PL" relationship with labels. however it still does not explain why order would matter.